# Galera , Maraidb - Port 4444 always Restart and Slaves Can not join to Cluster

Tags: mariadb, centos7, galera

I am working on Mariadb Cluster, I am using Centos 7 OS and Mariadb 10.1 .

I am trying to Join Nodes to cluster, I started the Cluster, I have 2 Nodes.

This is the first Node :

```
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
bind-address=0.0.0.0
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://Node1.IP,Node2.IP"
## Galera Cluster Configuration
wsrep_cluster_name="cluster"
## Galera Synchronization Configuration
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
## Galera Node Configuration
wsrep_node_address="Node1.IP"
wsrep_node_name="node1"
```

And I executed :

```
galera_new_cluster
```

This is the second Node

```
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
bind-address=0.0.0.0
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://Node1.IP,Node2.IP"
## Galera Cluster Configuration
wsrep_cluster_name="cluster"
## Galera Synchronization Configuration
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
## Galera Node Configuration
wsrep_node_address="Node2.IP"
wsrep_node_name="node2"
```

And I executed :

```
systemctl restart mariadb
Job for mariadb.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process. See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

In Node1 Mariadb :

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_cluster_size';
+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| wsrep_cluster_size | 1     |
+--------------------+-------+

And Sometimes For seconds :

+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| wsrep_cluster_size | 2     |
+--------------------+-------+
```

I found in **Node1**, **lsof -i:4444** :

```
Does not return anything
```

And In **Node2** , Sometimes **lsof -i:4444** for Seconds

```
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
rsync   2101 mysql    5u  IPv4 5510482      0t0  TCP *:krb524 (LISTEN)
rsync   2101 mysql    6u  IPv6 5510483      0t0  TCP *:krb524 (LISTEN)
```

And sometimes

```
Does not return anything
```

In **Node1**

```
firewall-cmd --list-ports
3306/tcp 4567/tcp 4567/udp 4444/tcp 4444/udp 4568/tcp
```

In **Node2**

```
firewall-cmd --list-ports
3306/tcp 4567/tcp 4567/udp 4444/tcp 4444/udp 4568/tcp
```

In **Node1**

```
nmap Node2.IP
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
3306/tcp closed mysql
4444/tcp closed krb524
4567/tcp closed tram
```

In **Node2**

```
nmap Node1.IP
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
3306/tcp open   mysql
4444/tcp closed krb524
4567/tcp open   tram
```

How Can I fix it ?

Thanks a million :D

Answer (score 1):

I could resolve it. Galera clucter never start with two nodes. You need three nodes for start galera cluster. After I prescribed the third node, the cluster started without any problems.